# Is there a way to get an AWS S3 object using a wildcard * nodeJS SDK V3?

Tags: amazon-s3, wildcard

I have the following objects in my S3 bucket:

```
123_foo_bar
123_bar_foo
638j7_they_good
xxx_something_else
```

I would like to know if is there a way to get all 123_* objects using the [GetObjectCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getobjectcommand.html)?
Here is a [code example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_s3_code_examples.html) by AWS but no mention to that wildcard usage.

Comment: You need to call [ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/listobjectsv2command.html) one or more times to list the objects, and select the ones you want to call GetObjectCommand individually on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards are not supported, however [there is a request property Prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) which should work if the text you want is at the start of the filename, and the [rest of the path before the text is the same](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html).

> prefix

```
Limits the response to keys that begin with the specified prefix.
```

Comment: Yes. To use prefix is a better practice. It will better organize files and will save effort when retrieve them.